# Selecting separate rows in for-next loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a For-Next loop,
at the beginning, I will select row 1&2, then row 1&3, then row 1&4 ...etc
I tried the following but excel would treat my "i" as column i instead of the row number. How this problem can be fixed?

```
Sub test123()
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 51
    Range("1:1,i:i").Select
    Selection.Copy
'other code
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert your variable **names** within a `String` - you need to include the **value** of the variable within the `String` instead.

```
Sub test123()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 51
        Range("1:1," & i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        'other code
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Note: There should be no need to actually `Select` the ranges:

```
Sub test123()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 51
        Range("1:1," & i & ":" & i).Copy
        'other code
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @ShaiRado - I should also have put a `With ActiveSheet` around it too - but one lesson at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and suggestion.

Comment: @YowE3K the codes work perfectly, but I don't really understand the meaning behind the code ("1:1," & i & ":" & i), can you please give me a hand

Comment: @Geoffrey The portion saying `"1:1," & i & ":" & i` is taking a string of `"1:1,"` and concatenating to it the value of your variable `i`, then concatenating the string `":"` and than concatenating the value of your variable `i` again.  So if the value of `i` is currently `3` then it is creating a final string of `"1:1,3:3"`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative way to go is using the `Union`, between each pair of `Rows` you want to copy:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test123()

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 51
    Union(Rows(1), Rows(i)).Copy
    'other code       
Next i

End Sub
```

**Note**: there's ne need to `Select` the range before copying it, you can directly use the copy on the fully qualified Range.